# Singular values of the differentation operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

I was trying to solve this exercise but I can't get to answer given in book:

Find the singular values of the operator D over $R_2[x]$ (That is polynomials with degree equal or less than 2) define as D(p)=p' where $p \in R_2[x]$ and p' is the derivate of the polynomial. And the inner product over $R_2[x]$ is :

$\langle p,q \rangle = \displaystyle{\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx}$.

So this is the way I'd tried to solve it:

First of all I took the base {1,x,$x^2$} and used gram-schmidt process to orthonormalised the set of vectors, {$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x,\sqrt{\frac{45}{8}}(x^2-\frac{1}{3})$}, and then I found the matrix of D, given that $D(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}})=0$, $D(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ and $D(\sqrt{\frac{45}{8}}(x^2-\frac{1}{3}))=2\sqrt{\frac{45}{8}}x=3\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}x$:

$\mathcal{M}(D)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Now the matrix of the adjoint operator is the transpose matrix of $\mathcal{M}(D)$, that is:

$\mathcal{M}(D^*)=\mathcal{M}(D)^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} & 0&0\\
0 & 3\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. So:

$\mathcal{M}(DD^*)=\mathcal{M}(D)\mathcal{M}(D^*)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{45}{2} &0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

So the singular values of D would be the positive squre of the eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathcal{M}(DD^*)$, that is the singular values of D would be $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{45}{2}}$. But according to the book the answer is wrong.

There might be just a silly mistake doing the maths but I can't see where is it. I would really appreciate any advice or hint you could give me.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that $M(D)$ is badly computed. Only the first column is right. In the second one, you should put the coordinates of $D(\sqrt{\frac32}x)$ **in the orthogonal basis**, not in the old one $1, x, x^2$.

Comment: You're totally right the second column should be ($\sqrt{3},0,0$) and the third column should be (0,$\sqrt{15}$,0). I t was in fact a silly mistake. Thanks so much @GiuseppeNegro